# Edit IEEEtran bibliography to add date after author names in the order

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am using shareLatex and overleaf v2. I do not care to learn how to type out the entire bst file or the syntax so much.

what i do want to do is make it so that bibliographies appear in the [name][date][title][edition][city published][publisher] and [pages] if needed then at the end [url].

I honestly have found IEEEtran to be closest, but they put the Date portion last.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If I understand your write-up correctly, you are (a) not happy with the IEEEtran bibliography style and (b) looking for a different bibliography style, specifically, one that places the `year` field immediately after the `author` block. Is this impression correct? If so, do you any salient formatting requirements -- beyond placing the year field immediately after the author block? Please advise.

Comment: Hey mico,  it seems like youve got it right, however i found that apacite worked best for me.